# Marking ember-data records as existing

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a somewhat unique circumstance where I wrote a caching layer for ember-data that serializes records to localstorage. When I deserialize my cache into the ember-data models I use `this.store.createRecord('model_name', cacheData);`. These records I am caching have existing values on the server. This works for me fine up until I want to `save()` the record. The save thinks the record is a new record even though it has an "id" attribute. When `save()` is called a POST is made to my application server instead of a PUT. Does anyone know a way to flag records in the store as not new.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `store.push` to add already existing records instead of `store.createRecord`

http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_push

Comment: I'll give that a try pretty soon. My local caching strategy has been getting increasingly complex as I try to expire cache data. I wish ember-data had some facility to cache to localstorage. This does seem cleaner than using createRecord.

Comment: I used your solution instead of messing with isNew. It is a cleaner solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find anything official, but models do have an [isNew](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#property_isNew) property. Since this is a read-only property, you can't set it directly, but you can set it on the currentState object like so:

```
var model = this.store.createRecord('model_name', cacheData);
model.set('currentState.parentState.isNew', false);

model.get('isNew') // => false
```

I can't speak to whether this is the best way to do it, but it should do what you're asking. Make sure you have good tests :)

Comment: That is awesome. I was searching around for an attribute exactly like that. Setting that attribute did the trick for me. I wish that Ember-data had some better baked in caching via localStorage. Thank you.

Comment: Technically, your answer was answered exactly what I was asking, but IgotT pointed out what I should be doing instead. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: I'm not saying that what you wrote is wrong, I'm just saying that `store.push` was what I really should have been doing in the first place.

Comment: On Ember 2.12 doing this has changed the 'new' state of another integration test. Kind of weird.